# Adding more textboxes to an asp:login control

Tags: asp.net, authentication, login-control

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms and making use of the  control. However I want to add 3 textboxes, email, password and dateofbirth. email and password come standard as username and password, but if I had a third textbox for date of birth (above the login button but below the email and password), in my code behind, the ID of this control is not recognised because its between the scope of the  tags.

Is there a way to add more controls with this  control and then authenticate them separately?

Comment: Andy,

Could you please explain how you did this? I have a similar need.

Thanks,
Daphne

Answer (score 4):

From Visual studio Design View you can convert the asp:LoginControl to a Template. This then exposes all the html within the control. You can then add what ever you want in there.

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1"
            runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                        Log In</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                            ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                            ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                                            ValidationGroup="Login1" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
```

In your code behind you will need to use `Login1.FindControl("")` for any additional controls that you want to access.

So for a new asp:textbox you could have it as:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" />
```

in the code behind:

```
TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("TextBox1");
```

Comment: Why is FindControl() needed?

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis `FindControl()` is required because the the target control is not directly accessible to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You are also able to add one or more additional controls to ASP Login control programmatically!
For example, you are able to add a new textbox like this:

```
// Override the OnInit() method.
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

  // Dynamically create controls
        var newTextBoxControl = new TextBox();
        newTextBoxControl.Text = "dfsdf";
        newTextBoxControl.ID = "PinCode";
        newTextBoxControl.MaxLength = 5;
        newTextBoxControl.CssClass="form-control";
        var targetControl=FindControlRecursive(Login1, "Login1_LoginButton");            
        targetControl.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0,txt);
}

private Control FindControlRecursive(Control control, string controlId)
{
    if (control.ClientID == controlId) return control;

    Control result = null;
    foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
        result = FindControlRecursive(childControl, controlId);

        if (result != null)
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```