# Nesting a button within asp:login

Tags: asp.net

I wan to be able to have a button within my login form but are not sure how to do it.

```
 <asp:login
        ID="seamenLogin" runat="server" 
        TitleText="<strong>Inloggning till sjöläkarwebben. Läkarintyg enligt Manilakonventionen</strong>"
        Inloggning med <a class='linkbutton' href='https://sjo-secure.transportstyrelsen.se/BUMSMedicalCertificateManila/Login.aspx'/>E-legitimation (BankID, Mobil BankID, ...)</a><br/><br/><br/>

        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="GreetButton" text="Say Hello!" />
        </form>

        Inloggning med användarnamn och lösenord kan fortfarande användas men vi<br/>rekommenderar att du övergår till inloggning med e-legitimation redan nu.<br/><br/>" 
        UserNameLabelText="Användarnamn:" 
        PasswordLabelText="Lösenord:"
        LoginButtonText="Logga in"
        DisplayRememberMe="False" 
        CreateUserText="<br/>Saknar du inloggningsuppgifter?"
        UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="Du måste ange användarnamn."
        FailureText="Ogiltigt användarnamn eller lösenord. Försök igen"
        PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="Du måste ange lösenord" 
        meta:resourcekey="seamenLoginResource1">
        <TitleTextStyle CssClass="heading1" HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
        <LabelStyle CssClass="textboxnamn" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px"/>
        <InstructionTextStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <LoginButtonStyle CssClass="loginbutton"/>
    </asp:login>
```

This obviously doesn't work because the element 'form' cannot be nested within the element 'login'

My question is:
Is there a way around this? Is there a way to nest a button in a login form by changing the structure or anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own LayoutTemplate:

```
<asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="submitLoginBtn" CommandName="Login" runat="server">Login</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="GreetButton" text="Say Hello!" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Comment: Check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761219/adding-more-textboxes-to-an-asplogin-control